# How to Prove that Uniform Cost Search algorithm always output optimal path

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

Is there any mathematical or reasonable way to prove that Uniform Cost Search algorithm always outputs optimal path?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness

Comment: PDF page 6: [http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hojjat/384f06/Lectures/Lecture03-4up.pdf](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hojjat/384f06/Lectures/Lecture03-4up.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean BFS, it can be proved by induction on the level in which the target node has been found.

1) If the level is 0 it is clearly optimal since there target and the source are the same.

2) Assume the optimality holds for all levels less than < n

3) If for some node the optimal length is n, the node before the final node has to be reached in less than n levels in an optimal manner. So by induction hypothesis, that node (the node before the final node) is in level n - 1 in the BFS tree, and since that node and the final node have an edge between them, the final node is reached in n levels which is optimal.